# Pouchdb Unknown Error

Tags: pouchdb, cloudant

I am using pouchdb 3.6.0 and syncing to cloudant inside a Chrome App (i.e. all clients are chrome browser).

The app is being used by approx 30 users so far and most of them are happy. However approx 3 users are experiencing a ' Database encountered an unknown error'.

Below is a image of the console on a problem client, unfortunately it is very difficult to debug a packaged app, so I am struggling to dig deeper - but was wondering if the 403 error is normal or not ???

The error message ('Database encountered an unknown error') is produced from

```
db.replicate.from(systemUrl).on('error', function (err) { //console log })
```

[image: console error]

Comment: update : I asked one of the problem users to try at home (instead of the office) and she reported that it worked perfectly. Could the 'unknown error' be related to intermittent / poor quality network connections ??? The 3 problematic users are all in the same office (but their other internet functions are all working, e.g. email, web browsing, dropbox, etc).

Comment: That looks like an issue with cookie authentication in Cloudant. Did you try asking Cloudant customer support for help?

Comment: I have been using basic authentication up until now... @nlawson I cant seem to find a direct way of setting cookie authentication for a PouchDB sync ... is the correct way through your [plugin](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication) ? I also found [this](http://www.mircozeiss.com/couchdb-security-and-pouchdb-authentication/)